# SSDT download guidance

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have SQL Server Management Studio. I've imported an excel file and learned how to write queries on the database.  I'm interested in a report templates.  I read about SSDT and assume that would be useful to me.  When I click on File > New > Project, my options don't include the "Business Intelligence" menu items (i.e. Reporting Services).

The Microsoft page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt
Where I downloaded SSDT, specifically refers to "Visual Studio."  Is that different than Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?  Will SSDT work with SS Management Studio, or do I need to downoad "Visual Studio" as well, or are they one in the same... a bit confused.  Thanks for any guidance on this.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) are not the same thing. SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) only works within Visual Studio, and has nothing to do with SSMS. If you want to use what SSDT offers, you will need a compatible version of Visual Studio to do so.

**Updated per request:**

SSMS is used to do development around the SQL Server stack, where VS is an all around development tool that you can use to build applications in many programming languages.

Is used to be that SSDT was called Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS), and was more of a stand-alone thing; it was really *off to the side* of the SQL Server stack that business intelligence pros needed to get their work done. Now, with SSDT, MS has made is fit a little more with VS project templates, although you still have to download it separately.

You need SSDT to develop SSRS reports, SSAS cubes and SSIS packages, and it includes tools to help you deploy those things to the appropriate location when you are done with development.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks very much.  Can you explain the difference between the two products, broadly?  Is Visual Studio more for template based report building and SSMS for pure coding?  I'm learning this stuff on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Richards!  Yes, this is very informative, I've found a bunch of great videos on this now that I know what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually SSDT will include a scaled back version of Visual Studio that will allow you to create Integration Services packages, including an IDE to create and edit Script Components.

Read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt#installing-ssdt-without-visual-studio-pre-installed